# Why can't I query from an activerecord relation using joins?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to figure out why this is producing an N + 1 query. Specifically, I want to get the count of upvotes, and thought that by using the joins it would. My goal is to order the results by the count of upvotes, however when I also want to report the count of upvotes for each entry, why does it query the database again for upvotes? Thanks :)

`self
 .joins(:upvotes)
 .group("#{self.table_name}.id")
 .order("count(upvotes.id) DESC")
 .includes(:creator, :categories)`

Comment: Please include more details: How are you accessing the count in your view?

Comment: what happens if you add `.to_sql` to the end of that query?  (often you can use that to spot what it's trying to do and how that differs from what you expect it's doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is going to be a common count, Rails has something called counter cache, that will store the count in the parent model, for easier querying.

I don't know your class name, so I called X.

In `Upvote`: `belongs_to :x, counter_cache: true`

Then you simply needs a `upvotes_count` fields in `X`

---

Being stored on X, you simply query X, sort by _upvotes_count_ and use that field to display it.